# How to gitignore a particular Java file or any folder or any XML file in Android project?

Tags: android, git, gitignore

I have a project in Bitbucket and I want to give access to one of my intern. I want to ignore certain Java files and certain file inside debug folder.

I have tried using the way, adding this line in my gitignore file:

```
/app/src/main/java/com/example/amanv/emulatordetection/NewActivity.class
```

However, this didn't work out.

I also tried:

```
/NewActivity.class
```

didn't work out too.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You can not ignore those files that you have previously committed, for that you have to remove those files from your git.**

1. To do that first go to your file directory.
2. Now type this command to remove the file from your git.

   **git rm --cached [filename]**
3. Now the file has been removed from your branch, and now
   you have to add the file name in your .gitignore file.

   **filename.java (Remember that the activity extension should be in java.)**
4. After that, add the files to the branch and then commit them. Then
   finally, push and you will see the files are ignored.

   [image: Check how i did...]

Answer (score 3):

Please mind, that the path of files you want to ignore with a `.gitignore` file are relative to the path of your `.gitignore` file in your repo.

so:

```
/NewActivity.class
```

means: ignore the file NewActivity.class in the same directory as .gitignore and **not in subdirectories**

```
NewActivity.class
```

means: ignore the file NewActivity.class in the same directory as .gitignore and **in all subdirectories**

If you want to use:
`/app/src/main/java/com/example/amanv/emulatordetection/NewActivity.class`
then your .gitignore file has to be located in a parent direcory of app, which has to be part of your repository of course.

Comment: So, suppose i have a strings.xml in the debug folder and i want to add it to gitignore. can i add the path of strings.xml in the gitignore file?

Comment: That depends on the location of the `.gitignore` file in your file system. If your `.gitignore` is in the same directory as `debug`, then you could add `/debug/strings.xml`. This way only the `strings.xml` file in your debug folder would be ignored. You could also add only `strings.xml`, this way all files named strings.xml in `debug` and other subdirectories would be ignored. You could also create a `.gitignore` file local in `debug` and add `/strings.xml`, to ignore the file only in `debug`.

Comment: Thanks. One more doubt, i have google-services.json inside my app folder and another inside my debug folder for different build. I want to .gitignore the one which is in app folder but not the debug folder one. So i created a new .gitignore inside the debug folder and write nothing in it and in main .gitignore i write google-services.json. will it work?

Comment: You should add `/google-services.json` to the `.gitignore` in your app folder to be sure. Then it should work.

Comment: will it ignor e the one in the debug folder as well?

Comment: No, the `/` means that only the file in the app folder will be ignored.

Comment: It isn't working. I have added /google-services.json inside .gitignore inside app folder. but it isn't removing the file from both the folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187127/discussion-between-wizzard-and-sniper).

Answer (score 1):

**I think the extension should be .java instead of .class.**

So instead of this

```
/app/src/main/java/com/example/amanv/emulatordetection/NewActivity.class
```

It should be this

```
/app/src/main/java/com/example/amanv/emulatordetection/NewActivity.java
```